# App settings bundle - ToggleSwitch

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

I am using in my app ToggleSwitch in app settings. My settings are in plist file.

```
Toggle Switch Elements are these:
Type (required) = Toggle Switch 
Title (required, localizable) = MyToggle 
Key (required) = enabled_preference 
DefaultValue (required) = (BOOL) YES;
 Value for ON = (BOOL) YES 
Value for OFF = (BOOL) NO
```

In app i do this to recognize:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
BOOL enabled = [defaults boolForKey:@"enabled_preference"]; 
NSLog(@"enabled = %i",enabled);
```

But when i first install app Toggle Switch is ON, but enabled = false. I can't understand why ?

Also maybe some could help how to do localization in that settings plist file ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because upon first launch your settings in settings bundle are not loaded to NSUserDefaults yet. You have to write a method to set your default values and register them with `registerDefaults`, and add it into `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` or any other method that gets executed on every launch.

Comment: But this happens just then when app is installed not every time app lunches

Comment: Reread my answer, your settings from settings bundle are _not_ in NSUserDefaults yet. Thats why you should provide defaults by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your appdidfinishlaunching method in your AppDelegate, it registers all the defaults for you at first launch.

```
- (void)registerDefaultsFromSettingsBundle
{
    /*
     before a user saves a nsdefault the entries in the settings bundle config file are not registereed.  
     The function loops through each preference in the root.plist of the settings.bundle file and registers each key that is not readable (therefore not registered).
     */
    //NSLog(@"Registering default values from Settings.bundle");
    NSUserDefaults * defs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defs synchronize];

    NSString *settingsBundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Settings" ofType:@"bundle"];

    if(!settingsBundle)
    {
        NSLog(@"Could not find Settings.bundle");
        return;
    }

    NSDictionary *settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[settingsBundle stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Root.plist"]];
    if(!settings)
        return;

        NSArray *preferences = [settings objectForKey:@"PreferenceSpecifiers"];
    if(!preferences)
        return;
        NSMutableDictionary *defaultsToRegister = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:[preferences count]];

    for (NSDictionary *prefSpecification in preferences)
    {
        NSString *key = [prefSpecification objectForKey:@"Key"];
        if (key)
        {
            // check if value readable in userDefaults
            id currentObject = [defs objectForKey:key];
            if (currentObject == nil)
            {
                // not readable: set value from Settings.bundle
                id objectToSet = [prefSpecification objectForKey:@"DefaultValue"];
                [defaultsToRegister setObject:objectToSet forKey:key];
               // NSLog(@"Setting object %@ for key %@", objectToSet, key);
            }
                    }
    }

    [defs registerDefaults:defaultsToRegister];
    [defaultsToRegister release];
    [defs synchronize];
}
```